# How are co-countable sets useful and important in topology?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

> In mathematics, a cocountable subset of a set X is a subset Y whose complement in X is a countable set. In other words, Y contains all but countably many elements of X. Since the rational numbers are a countable subset of the reals, for example, the irrational numbers are a cocountable subset of the reals. If the complement is finite, then one says Y is cofinite. [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountability)

This idea came up in a few posts related to topology I saw on the site. My question is, what is the significance of a set being co-countable? The definition, in my opinion, is very simple to understand but I can't understand why it would be something which is important.

Thanks.

Comment: The co-countable sets form a [topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology) that is an important example in topology. If the base set is uncountable, then the topology is not Hausdorff, but sequential limits are still unique, for example.

Comment: They aren't an important in and of themselves, but they are used to give examples of topological spaces (co-countable topology and co-finite topology on a set) which are simple to understand and which help illuminate some ideas by providing examples/counterexamples.

Comment: " If the base set is uncountable, then the topology is not Hausdorff, " did not know that. Did not know that O_o @TheoBendit

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a set, the co-countable topology on $X$ is the topology which consists of $\emptyset$ together with all co-countable subsets of $X$. And this topology is useful to have in mind to find examples. For instance, if $X$ is uncountable (if $X$ in countable, the co-countable topology is simply the discrete topology), then a sequence converges if and only if it is almost constant. But the same thing is true for the discrete topology. Therefore, two distinct topologies may lead to the same concept of convergent sequence.